# Why does PostgreSQL treat a value in my query as if it's a column name?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm using Npgsql with C# to communicate with my PostgreSQL database.  All names used in my database are mixed case, so in the query I make sure I use double quotes around each name.  Here is how I am sending the query:

```
// construct an insert query
string insertQuery = "insert into \"Update\" (\"Vehicle\",\"Property\",\"Value\") " + 
                     "values (" + vehicleNum.ToString() + ",\"" + propertyName + 
                     "\",\"" + propertyValue + "\")";

// execute the query
NpgsqlCommand insertCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
insertCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

By inserting a breakpoint and checking, I verified that the string `insertQuery` looks this before it is sent:

```
insert into "Update" ("Vehicle","Property","Value") values (12345,"EngineSpeed","50")
```

When I send this query, PostgreSQL gives me an error, which is wrapped up in an Npgsql exception that states: `ERROR: 42703: column "EngineSpeed" does not exist`

From my query, it should be evident that `EngineSpeed` is not a column, it is the value of the `Property` column, so naturally a column with that name is unlikely to exist.  So why does PostgreSQL treat my query this way, and how can I solve this issue?  Has my query been constructed the wrong way?

Comment: ... is your table really named 'Update'?

Comment: Yeah, that's not a great idea.

Comment: Doesn't Npgsql support placeholders? Building an SQL string by hand like that really isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Phill, yes the table's name is Update, because it stores Updates.  Sounded like the best name for it at the time, and will it really cause any problems?

Comment: Your code is EXTREMELY vulnerable to trivial SQL injection attacks. Please use parameterised queries via prepared statements.

Comment: Yes, Npgsql as defined by .net data providers documentation, has support for parameters. You may want to use NpgsqlCommand.Parameters collection when building your queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use single quotes to quote strings. Double quotes are used to denote column names.

Answer (score 2):

No, from the query you show it's evident that EngineSpeed is a column because it's escaped as such.

You also weren't taking care to make sure the values passed were escaped, which can be a serious security issue.

You want `insert into "Update" ("Vehicle","Property","Value") values (12345,'EngineSpeed','50')`

Which you could safely provide with:

```
string insertQuery = "insert into \"Update\" (\"Vehicle\",\"Property\",\"Value\") " + 
                     "values (" + vehicleNum.ToString() + ",'" + propertyName.Replace("'", "''") + 
                     "','" + propertyValue.Replace("'", "''") + "')";
```

Though you are better off using parameters with NPGSQL, which will handle this for you, including all of those nasty edge cases our unit tests are full of :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  What is the difference between the code you have posted here, and the code I already had?

Comment: Yours puts EngineSpeed in `"` Mine (assuming no typos) puts it in `'`. I also check to replace `'` within it with doubled (`Engine'Speed` would become `'Engine''Speed'`) which is one of the correct ways to escape it (there are a few other valid ways to do strings in PostgreSQL). Again though, you'd be better using NpgsqlParameter and having NPGSQL work this out for you. There are some other gotchas with other parameter types, and Npgsql should have them all by now (I did most of the work for the array types myself, but that was mostly learning from the prior work of others).

Comment: Oh my bad, I had overlooked the changes you had made.  Thank you.

Comment: If you use parameters, Npgsql will take care of all those things for you. It is simpler and will help you avoid sql injection problems.

Comment: I think the best bit isn't that it catches the dangers you know about for you, but it catches a few that you may not even know about. The escape rules for composite types can be tricky. (And hi @FranciscoJunior good to see you here).

Comment: Thanks guys, I will use parameters.